Using function keys for RegisterHotKey function
Can you use function keys for a Macro tool in VB.NET? I have debug.writeline for it to notify which buttons I am pressing but for some reason it's not detecting any function keys are being pressed in the console output.
This is the statement here:
Private Shared Function HookCallback(nCode As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    If nCode >= 0 AndAlso (wParam = CType(257, IntPtr) OrElse wParam = CType(256, IntPtr)) Then
        Dim vkCode As Integer = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam)
        Debug.WriteLine("Key pressed: " & CType(vkCode, Keys).ToString())
    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)

End Function
This is the full code of the macro, but I just need to know what I am doing wrong:
    Private Const HOTKEY_ID_F1 As Integer = 1
Private Const HOTKEY_ID_F2 As Integer = 2

Private notifyIcon As NotifyIcon
Private Shared hookProc As LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate = AddressOf HookCallback
Private Shared hookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(hWnd As IntPtr, id As Integer, fsModifiers As UInteger, vk As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(hWnd As IntPtr, id As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Public Const MOD_ALT As UInteger = &H1
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

Private Sub MainScreen_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Redirect console output to TextBox if it's initialized
    If txtConsoleOutput IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim writer As New TextBoxWriter(txtConsoleOutput)
        Console.SetOut(writer)
    Else
        ' Show an error message if TextBox is not initialized
        MessageBox.Show("Error: txtConsoleOutput TextBox control is not initialized.")
    End If

    ' Initialize the system tray icon
    InitializeSystemTrayIcon()

    ' Set the global keyboard hook
    hookID = SetHook(hookProc)

    ' Register hotkeys
    RegisterHotKeys()
End Sub

Private Sub RegisterHotKeys()
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, HOTKEY_ID_F1, MOD_ALT, Keys.F1)
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, HOTKEY_ID_F2, MOD_ALT, Keys.F2)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Select Case m.WParam.ToInt32()
            Case HOTKEY_ID_F1
                InsertTextIntoPictureBox("PictureBox1")
            Case HOTKEY_ID_F2
                InsertTextIntoPictureBox("PictureBox2")
        End Select
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

The above is on the MainForm but I have a UserControl for the MacInjection UserControl and this is the code I have for the F1 Key:
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    ' Debug message to check if ProcessCmdKey is called
    Debug.WriteLine("ProcessCmdKey in MacInjection: " & keyData.ToString())

    ' Implement your logic here based on the key code received
    Select Case keyData
        Case Keys.F1
            Debug.WriteLine("F1 Key")
            AddInformationToPictureBox1()
            Return True ' Indicate that the key has been handled
        Case Keys.F2
            AddInformationToPictureBox2()
            Return True ' Indicate that the key has been handled
    End Select

    ' Pass unhandled key press events to the base class for further processing
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function

The debug.writeline "F1 Key" is not being hit. Any reasons?

Me.Handle is tricky, it is not a stable value.  If you do something like tinkering with the form's ShowInTaskbar property (likely with a tray icon app) then Me.Handle will change and the keys are not registered anymore.  Use the HandleCreated event to call RegisterHotKeys().

But it works for all other keys except the function keys. When the app is minimized it is writing to the console all the keystrokes but it is not registering the function keys. Any idea?

"all the keystrokes" is hard to interpret, you are not supposed to see any key when the user interface is minimized.  But does explain why the function keys are special, they are hot keys.  Post more code.

I have updated the original question.
Kindly advise.

It is like I guessed, when you make a key a hot-key then it no longer operates like a normal key.  You won't see it back in ProcessCmdKey().  Feature, not a bug.

OK, great. This means there must be a problem with the add information method. I went and made it accessible in the system tray and added debug.writelines to see if it was working capturing keystrokes when the application was closed but for some reason it isn't hitting the "F1 Key" when I use Alt + f1. I will need to look into this more.

If this is WinForms, I don't think you need to hook windows events.
Just set KeyPreview to True in the Form Designer, then handle the Form.KeyUp event
Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
    MsgBox("F1 pressed")
  End If
End Sub

This event will fire before the selected control's events fire.

Yes, it is a WinForms. I am still having issues where the f1 key is not being registered when it's being hit. KeyPreview is set as True. It is registering all other keys except the f1 keys.

I have updated the original question. Kindly advise.
